# Error while trying to run project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've hit a brick wall and need your help, every time I try to run a new or existing project on my Microsoft VS2010 I get these error message:

> "Error while trying to run project : could not load file or assembly "project name" or one of its
>   dependencies . The module was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest. "

Some of the advices I got was to run the following on VS2010 Command prompt; `- "devenv.exe /resetskippkgs"` which didn't help.

I also tried uninstalling and re-installing VS2010 all in vain. Please help because I am completely stuck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try saving project using Save All on c:\ drive before running.  I sometimes see this issue the first time a project is created on a computer.

Comment: I tried that just now and it didn't work.